# DataTables diacritics not working correctly

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, datatables

I'm using [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) to work with data but there is a problem with language specific characters like Ě, Š, Č, ... I have city "Třebíč" but if I enter "Třebič" into searchbox, the data that come to server are "tÅebÃ­Ä". The charset is UTF-8 in every page.

Is it possible to work with these characters in JavaScript and DataTables?

Comment: Please post the code you are using, preferably a self-contained demo document that triggers the problem.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela well... I can't do it. I can show the HTML/JavaScript demo but I can't show fully working demo with the server part because I use CQ5 CMS on server that is not visible from the internet...

Comment: It is sufficient to post an example that submits the form data to some service that simply echoes back what it gets, such as my simple utility http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo8.cgi (which expects UTF-8 encoded data).